# Problems With Formatting a Python Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I've been trying to figure this out for three days now. I have been working on the following project:

Create a loop that will output all the positive numbers less than 500 that are evenly divisible by both 3 and 7.
Increment your loop counter by 1 during each iteration.
Use a logical operator when determining if a number is divisible by 3 and 7.
Beginning on a new line, output the multiples on a single line with 4 spaces in between each number.
Once you have outputted five numbers, move to the next line and carry on.

My issue is that I have no idea how to break up the output to five per row.
Here's the code that I have so far:

```
for y in range(1, 500):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 7 == 0:
        print(y, end="    ")
        y = y + 1
```

As expected, the output is in a single line as I have to idea how to split it up every five outputs:

```
21    42    63    84    105    126    147    168    189    210    231    252    273    294    315    336    357    378    399    420    441    462    483
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `y` is incremented automatically by the `for y in range ...` loop.  Adding 1 to it with `y = y + 1` is useless.

Comment: You need to keep a SEPARATE counter to count the numbers you actually wrote, then do `if ctr % 5 == 0:` / `print()`.  Alternatively, just add `if y % 105 == 0:` / `print()`.

Comment: @jona Other contributors have found problems with your code. You should update your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
printedItems = 0
for y in range(1, 500):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 7 == 0:
        print(y, end="    ")
        printedItems += 1
        if printedItems % 5 == 0:
            print() #Just to break the line
```

Another tip: remove y = y + 1 because "in range" does that automatically.

I wrote it this way to facilitate understanding. If you're looking for a more sophisticated way, you can change the end of the print statement to \n (line break) when printedItems % 5 == 0

```
printedItems = 0
for y in range(1, 500):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 7 == 0:
        printedItems += 1
        end = "\n" if printedItems % 5 == 0 else "    "
        print(y, end=end)
```

Thumbs up if it was helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't realize that y = y + 1 was redundant in this case.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
for y in range(1, 500):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 7 == 0:
        print(y, end="    ")
        # y = y + 1 (not needed)

        if y % 5 == 0: # has to be INSIDE the other if-block
            print("\n")
```

The code above should do what you want. But it only works as long as you do not change the 3 or the 7 to numbers divisible by 5. Then you would have to add a counting variable like this:

```
n = 1
for y in range(1, 500):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 7 == 0:
        print(y, end="    ")
        if n % 5 == 0:
            print("\n")
        n += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
res = []
for y in range(1, 500):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 7 == 0:
        res.append(str(y))
for i in range(0, len(res), 5):
    print("    ".join(res[i:i+5]))
```

Comment: If you think your answer is wrong, you help the community by either correcting or deleting it.

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.